# 「日本では美味しい和食が食べられる」と「日本は美味しい和食が食べられる」は違う？

Tags: grammar, syntax

> （1）“日本では美味しい和食が食べられる”
>
> （2）“日本は美味しい和食が食べられる”

どっちも使えるんですね。意味もわかりますけど、もうちょっと詳しい文法を知りたいです。

私はこう思います(正しいかどうかわからない)：

> “日本では美味しい和食が食べられる”　⇒　“私は日本で美味しい和食が食べられる”　から　変わった文です。(この場合主語がつくと、自然な日本語とは思わないけど、私にとってもっと理解しやすいと思う。)
>
> “日本は美味しい和食が食べられる”　⇒　“私は日本で美味しい和食が食べられる”　から　変わった文ではなく　”日本は私は美味しい和食を食べられる”　から　変わった文です。

私は、他には　“へは　には　とは　etc”　と　“は”　だけ　を比べる場合も　この例文と同じだと思います。
最後に、日本語が下手ですので、私が言ってる意味が先生たちに分かるかどうかちょっと心配してますので、英語でもっと説明します。

I think that the phrase "日本は" in sentence（1）is just like the meaning of "about Japan" in English and doesn`t emphasize "where".
If I try to translate it, I think it would be "About Japan, I can eat delicious Japanese food there"）

And, the "日本では"　in sentence（2）, I think, the meaning would be "In Japan" and somehow with kind of emphasis about that. 
If I translate it, I think it would be "In Japan, I can eat delicious Japanese food."

And, in other cases, I think we also can apply the same rule to them, like “日本は旅行に行きたいです”　is kind of like "About Japan, I want to go there."
And, “日本には旅行に行きたいです”　is like "I want to go to Japan."

I know I barely hear “日本は旅行に行きたいです” because of the lack of "に", but in some cases, “に　と　へ　etc”　are optional and don't play an important role.

So, Finally, I want to know the ideas from you guys because all of the explanations above are just my opinions. 
No matter what I said is correct or not, I hope you guys will explain the grammars to me.
Thank you very much.
質問が多くてすみません。

Comment: There is not much difference between both.

Answer (score 3):

Roughly saying, you're right.

Compared with 日本では…, the sentence with 日本は… lacks solid image of a grammatical case, and are likely to appear along with another sentence in which 日本 doesn't function as a locative case.

e.g. 旅行するならどこだろうか？ 日本だろうか？ 日本は美味しい和食が食べられる・・・

You say 日本で美味しい和食が食べられる”　から　変わった文, but whether what you say is right or not depends on what you mean by 変わった. If you mean "topicalized", you are right. However, if you mean "interchangeable", it's not.

Off topic; 「どっちも使えるんですね」は「どっちも使えるんです**よ**ね」としてください。

Answer (score 2):

> （1）“[日本]{にほん}**では**[美味]{おい}しい[和食]{わしょく}が[食]{た}べられる”
>
> （2）“日本**は**美味しい和食が食べられる”

The difference, the way I see it, is that while (1) is a complete sentence by any standard, (2) would only be considered a complete sentence by the standard  of informal and/or colloquial speech.

「日本**では**おいしい和食が食べられる。」, without adding anything, is simply a good and natural-sounding sentence all by itself.  I am unsure as to why you think it is strange.  (Sorry, I personally do not write 「おいしい」 using kanji.)

「日本**は**おいしい和食が食べられる。」, while any Japanese-speaker would understand it if you said it, just leaves a feeling of unnaturalness and incompleteness in one's ear.  It would become a complete and more natural-sounding sentence if one added words to it as in:

「日本**は**おいしい和食が食べられる**国です**。」

「日本**は**おいしい和食が食べられる**ので、[大好]{だいす}きです**。」

「日本**は**おいしい和食が食べられる**ので、[毎年行]{まいとしい}きます**。」

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry that my words made you misunderstand me. The one I think unnatural is  "私は日本で美味しい和食が食べられる"  because Japanese people usually drop a subject in a sentence, but I think that is the original form of "日本では美味しい和食が食べられる". 
Do you think the way I explain "は"　and　”には　とは　へは　etc ” is right??(I mean the explanations on my question area)
Thank you again.